# Spoilers : Main Story did I miss something?

Tags: bravely-default

If you read this PLEASE make sure you finished the game. If not,  leave this page right now. This may contain content that can spoil you and I really don't want you to be spoiled about this amazing game.

> So I went through 4 worlds (reanimating 4 crystals in each) and when I was in the 5th I knew that Airy was lying. It was right at the beginning of chapter 8. So I tried to just destroy the wind crystal and it worked. So I went through chapter 8 in like 2 minutes. Though I wonder, how long can you keep reanimating crystals before the main story leads you to destroy one? What happens if you destroy a crystal in the first world?

Comment: I am hoping that the Spoilers tag in the question is enough. I haven't gotten the 'true ending' yet but I destroyed the wind crystal right away in Chapter 5 and I fight Airy's two forms and then it just sends you 'back before you destroyed the crystal'. I don't know the differences between the endings yet.

Answer (score 2):

Main Story Line Spoilers Below

Your first question:

> Though I wonder, how long can you keep reanimating crystals before the main story leads you to destroy one?
>  Chapter 8 is the last chapter in the game. In order to get the true ending, you actually won't be  destroying *any* crystals. You will enter one final world at the end of chapter 8. In that world, you will not awaken or destroy any crystals.

---

Your second Question:

> What happens if you destroy a crystal in the first world?
>  You actually cannot destroy crystals in the first world. You are not allowed the opportunity. You can destroy crystals starting in chapter 5 (world 2). The place that makes the most sense (IMO) to destroy a crystal is the Earth Crystal in chapter 6 because the false ending references events that do not happen until chapter 6.